# Download audio file to Windows Phone part by part and play it along the download

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-phone-7, media-player, audio-streaming

I want to allow users to download (cache) audio files locally in their Isolated Storage, but to be able to start listening to it as it is downloading. My application can be downloading chunks of data to the phone and will be converting them to MediaElement to play. Besides that, it will be building up an array that the media file is and will eventually, when it is all downloaded, save it to an Isolated Storage.

I can have a custom app on the web to feed the media files, so I am in control of the protocol, if necessary.

My questions for this scenario are :

1. Implementation-wise, am I better of using some media streaming (that supports caching), or am I good with just publishing files for http download?
2. Is it better to implement my own client-server media exchange mechanism using WCF, or will I be able to just download the chunks of files from HTTP?
3. If a file is large (90MB or so) will I be able to fit it in memory before I serialize it to an Isolated Storage? If not, is it possible to do a part-by-part serialization to Windows Phone Isolated Storage?

I can't just use files from Media Library, since (and it is very very bad) there is no way to set a play position of an song from my application. In case I am to play an audio book, and it is presented as a single audio file, I am stuck with playing it over from the start each time a user tries to play it from my application.

Sorry for the long question and thank you in advance for answering.